# Filter multiple columns in table

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, multiple-columns

My code filters one column then prints.

I need to filter based on two columns and then print. I.e. filter based on engineer name (column 1) and route (column 2). Right now, it filters on engineer name (column 1).

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub filterandprint()

    Dim TempWks As Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
                
    'change to match your worksheet name
    Set wks = Worksheets("Table")
        
    Set TempWks = Worksheets.Add      'creates temporary worksheet

    wks.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the arrows

    'assumes headers only in row 1, columns(1) will be the number of the column you base your filtering
    'this copies the unique filtering and pastes it on a new temp worksheet
    wks.Columns(1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
      CopyToRange:=TempWks.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    With TempWks
        Set myRng = .Range("a2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    'looping
    With wks
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myCell.Value
            '.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=myCell.Value
            .PrintOut Preview:=True
        Next myCell
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWks.Delete    'deletes temporary worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `wks.Columns(1).AdvancedFilter` with `wks.Range("A:B").AdvancedFilter`

Comment: I did try that and it copies the first two columns onto the temporary worksheet, which is great, but it still only filters based off of the values in the first column.

Comment: For anyone else searching for an answer, edited the above looping section to the below and it worked:
`Dim iLoop As Integer

'looping
With wks
    For iLoop = 2 To 65
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TempWks.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TempWks.Cells(iLoop, 2).Value
        .PrintOut Preview:=True
     Next iLoop
End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWks.Delete    'deletes temporary worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`

Comment: you can actually add an answer to your own question. This is preferred for future users to more easily find what fixed your problem :)

Comment: ah! thank you - new to this, any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else searching for an answer, edited the above looping section to the below and it worked:

```
   ...

    Dim iLoop As Integer

    'looping
    With wks
        For iLoop = 2 To 65
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TempWks.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TempWks.Cells(iLoop, 2).Value
            .PrintOut Preview:=True
        Next iLoop
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWks.Delete    'deletes temporary worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```